# Proving triangular inequality for any metric with $|a-b|$ rather than $|a+b|$ as part of it

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If I am trying to prove triangular inequality for a metric with $|a-b|$ in it, and any other quality, to prove triangular inequality(for showing its a metric) do I prove:

$$|a+b|\leq |a+c|+|b+c|$$

Or rather do I want to prove:
$$|a-b|\leq|a-c|+|b-c|$$

The goal is to show this is a metric(Not this specifically, but anything with a minus in the absolute value!)

Comment: What are $f,g$? Also, your second formula *is* true, so what here is not a metric? Please, rewrite your question as it is very unclear.

Comment: @5xum Okay sorry. I mean that when I have any metric with $|a-b|$ as part of it. I.e. if I were proving $\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1} |f(x)-g(x)|$ on the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, would I prove the triangular inequality with the minuses(that are in the metric) or prove it with the pluses?

Comment: Why would you prove it with the pluses if there are no pluses in the definition of the metric?

Comment: @5xum So that's a no I guess :P. Some answer key did it that way and I was confused, since I thought it was $d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(b,c)$

Comment: I'm also confused about your sentence "this is not a metric", since what you wrote clearly *is* a metric.

Comment: @5xum I didn't say that, I was trying to say, The goal is to show that things of this class are a metric(via the method of pluses or minuses in the proof), not necessarily to prove only this localized problem

Answer (score 0):

$|a-b|=|a-c+c-b|\leq|a-c|+|c-b|=|a-c|+|b-c|$ if you know that $|-x|=|x|$.

A space where all this makes sense is a [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) and the relevant axiom is $|\lambda a|=|\lambda|\, |a|$.